# Android: Initial requests on app start

Tags: android, android-activity

My Android application needs to do an initial http request on app start to fetch a config json file from a RESTful service. This request is done by [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)
As soon as the application gets the data, the MainActivity starts. I also defined some deeplinks, to open a WebView in my application with a given URI. The deeplinks have to be handled by the SplashActivity as the config needs to be loaded first by Volley. I don't know if this is the right way to handle this. 
Maybe it would be an option to request the config in the Application class, so that the config is always available, no matter which Activity starts first?

Comment: Requesting the config from Application Class is a better option.

Comment: Can you explain, how to handle the asynchronous request? The MainActivity should only appear, if the request is done.

Comment: have added an answer...might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way.
In your Splash activity you should handle the incoming intent with your deeplinks, fire up your Volley request and only then you should move on with your logic.

BTW, in the meanwhile, you should show the user some loader/progress and handle failures of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making an asynchronous call in the Application class, you can make the request with a callback and show the required activity.

```
public interface ConfigListener {
    public void onConfigReceived(List<ofSomething> list,  boolean error, String message);
}

private void requestConfig(){
        final DownloadUsingVolley downloader = new DownloadUsingVolley(getActivity());
        downloader.retrieveData(new ConfigListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigReceived(List<ofSomething> list, boolean error, String message) {
                //Show your required activity here
            }
        });
}

private void retrieveData(String url, final ConfigListener configListener){
    final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                //parse
                configListener.onConfigReceived(result,false,null);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                configListener.onConfigReceived(0,true,e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            configListener.onConfigReceived(0,true,volleyError.getMessage());
        }
    });
    //adding request into the queue
    ApplicationClass.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request,"aTag");
}
```